# Create a new ArrayList from new variables and old ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The examples I've seen online always include explicit values to add to an ArrayList. However, I have created an ArrayList, reading from a file. I read each word from the file and assigned it a score. Now, I have to create a new ArrayList that adds each word from the file and its accompanying score. I can't find any examples online that deal with this.

EDIT: ERRORS ARE GONE, BUT I HAVE A PRINT STATEMENT BELOW THAT IS NOT PRINTING. I'M NOT SURE HOW TO FIGURE OUT IF I SUCCESSFULLY CREATED THE NEW LIST.

I used:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
 
    words.add(in.next());
}
```

to create my initial ArrayList.

I thought I could use something similar for the new one, but it's not working.

```
ArrayList<NewList> wordlist = new ArrayList<NewList>();
while (in.hasNext()) {
    value = in.nextInt();
    word = in.next();

    wordlist.add(NewList(value, word));
    System.out.println(wordlist);
}
```

THE PRINT STATEMENT ABOVE IS NOT PRINTING. TRYING TO TROUBLESHOOT THAT NOW.

Adding my class and constructor:

```
public class NewList {
    private int value;
    private String word;

    // Constructs a new list
    public NewList(int value, String word) {
        this.value = value;
        this.word = word;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question has little to do with how `ArrayList` works and is more that you don't seem to know how to create objects using a constructor in general. The short answer is that you need to construct an Object of `NewList` by calling a constructor possibly by doing `new NewList(value, word)` (We don't know what constructors are available because you didn't include the code). I recommend reading a tutorial about [Object creation in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: in your class NewList you need a constructor `public NewList(final int value, final String word)`, then you could use `wordList.add(  new  NewList(value,word));`. 

But actually, you are looking for a java.util.HashMap<Integer,String> to store key-value associations.

Comment: I added the code that I used to create the constructor. I realized a couple of mistakes based on your feedback. Thank you!! It's not printing what I want it to print yet, but the error I had before is gone. Now I just have to figure out why it's not printing the new list.

Comment: Also, sorry. I haven't learned HashMaps yet, so I'm not allowed to use them. They have been suggested to me for other portions of my code earlier on and they seem like they would help. I'm just not at that point in my experience yet. Someday!

Comment: If you're using private for the attributes you'll need to have getters as well in `NewList` class.

Comment: If you keep changing the question then it changes the meaning of the comments and answers - which makes any answer useless to future readers.  Try to limit editing to the addition or cleaning of things.  To wit - you have omitted how you generate and store the scores.  In the first block you are reading all of the words from one stream.  In the second you are alternatively reading words and values from a single stream.  The data model you created seems reasonable but the name is misleading (i.e. its not a List) - consider renaming to WordValue or something like that.